Shadcn/ui dialog closes unexpectedly and things becomes unclickable after that
I am using react and typescript and i have a ProgressBoard component which displays all the issues for a project, when i click on a IssueCard component which is wrapped in an IssueDialog. IssueDialog uses IssueCard as a trigger so when i click on it it opens a dialog containing IssuePage inside the dialog where i have a dropdown menu also from shadcn which i use to update the status of the issue.
The problem is when i change the status and to reflect that change update the global context of allIssues the dialog closes, the allIssues context gets updated but everything becomes unclickable, and this only happens when i update the context and not when i update the currIssue status.
here is the code
Progress Board:
{
allIssues.filter((issue) => {
    return issueSearch.toLowerCase() === ""
    ? issue
    : issue.title.toLowerCase().includes(issueSearch.toLowerCase()) ||
    issue.key.toLowerCase().includes(issueSearch.toLowerCase());
    }).map((issue) => {
        if (issue.status === status) {
            return <IssueCard key={issue._id} issue={issue} />;
        }
})}

IssueCard:
<IssueDialog issue={issue}>
    <div className="flex flex-col p-2 m-1 bg-white h-fit rounded-sm border border-slate-300 shadow-md cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-50 transition-all duration-150">
        <div className="text-sm pb-4 pl-1">{issue.title}</div>
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <div className="mr-2">
            <svg
              fill="#407cdd"
              className="w-6 h-6"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              stroke="#407cdd"
            >
              <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" strokeWidth="0"></g>
              <g
                id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
              ></g>
              <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
                <path d="M7 5a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H7zm4 10.414-2.707-2.707 1.414-1.414L11 12.586l3.793-3.793 1.414 1.414L11 15.414z"></path>
              </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div className="text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600">{issue.key}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </IssueDialog>


IssueDialog:
<Dialog>
    <DialogTrigger asChild>{children}</DialogTrigger>
    <DialogContent className="min-w-[65vw] min-h-[60vh] top-[40%] max-h-[70vh]">
        <IssuePage issue={issue} />
    </DialogContent>
</Dialog>

IssuePage:
async function handleStatusChange(status: string) {
    try {
        await axiosPrivate.post(`/issues/update-status/${currIssue._id}`, {
        status,
        });
        setCurrIssue({ ...currIssue, status });
        setAllIssues((prev) => prev.map((issue) =>
          issue._id === currIssue._id ? { ...issue, status } : issue
        ));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

What should happe is when i click on an issueCard it should open a dialog for the issue and i can change the status of the issue while staying in the modal until i manually close it and have the allIssue context updated when i go back.
I tried using zustand also but the problem persists so i believe it is something to do with shadcn or how i have implemented the dialog because it is a bit messy.
